# translate g++ code to clion environment

Tags: c++, c++11, clion

I am new in `clion`. on gcc i always use:

```
g++  bin/obj/main.o -o bin/main -lboost_filesystem -lboost_system -lcrypto
```

How to do it in clion?

It seems my `CMakeList` does not work:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
project(motion_simulation)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(motion_simulation ${SOURCE_FILES})
link_libraries(lboost_filesystem)
link_libraries(lboost_system)
link_libraries(lcrypto)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try including the keyword "CMake" into your search next time. This question is actually not CLion specific because CLion actually uses CMake as buildsystem.
CMake is very well documented, and you should be able to find a lot of answers regarding your problem.

You could first try to get rid of that "l":

```
link_libraries(boost_filesystem)
```

If that doesn't work you should take a look how the find_package() command works. http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake:How_To_Find_Libraries

And here is a detailed explanation how to find Boost libs and include directory.
http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindBoost.html

Answer (score 1):

As you are using CMake 3.1 you can use some more advanced features of CMake.

With `CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD` you can select which C++ version you want to use and CMake will select the corresponding compiler flags (see [docs](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/manual/cmake-compile-features.7.html)).

`link_libraries` is one possibility, but it has to be called before `add_executable` or `add_library`. The alternative is `target_link_libraries` which links only to a single target, but can also manage transitive dependencies ([docs](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.1/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#transitive-usage-requirements)).

CMake comes with `find_package` modules for OpenSSL and Boost to find dependencies and with the option `REQUIRED`, you can ensure that they are found on the system. Boost also supports `COMPONENTS` to select which libraries you need.

In case you ever work on a system, where OpenSSL and Boost are not installed in `/usr/`, you can already use `target_include_directories` to specify where the headers for your executable is found. Like `target_link_libraries`, `target_include_directories` can work with transitive dependencies, in this case `PRIVATE`.

```
 cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.1)
 project(motion_simulation)

 set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)

 find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS filesystem system)
 find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)

 set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
 add_executable(motion_simulation ${SOURCE_FILES})
 target_include_directories(motion_simulation PRIVATE ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS} ${OPENSSL_INCLUDE_DIR})
 target_link_libraries( motion_simulation PRIVATE ${Boost_LIBRARIES} ${OPENSSL_LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: Thanks Finn for your attention.